# Extending basic limit theorem to periodic case

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am curious about a proof for the generalization of the basic limit theorem in stochastic processes. That is:

$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} P_{jj}^{(ns)} =\frac{s}{t_{jj}}$ where s is the period of the irreducible and positive recurrent markov chain and $t_{jj}$ is the mean recurrence time. I feel like this proof should be available in common textbooks but I just cannot seem to find..If someone could point me towards a reference or give me some hints on how I can approach the proof..I would appreciate it!

Thanks

Comment: That there is no specific detailed proof in the texts you searched is not very surprising since then, the Markov chain $Y$ defined by $Y_n=X_{ns}$ is irreducible, aperiodic and positive recurrent, hence the classical theorem applies to $Y$ and you get the result.

Comment: Ah I think I get it! That would divide the mean recurrence time by s. One point of confusion tho..the transition matrix for $Y_n$ is $P^s$? If so my intuition says that divides the space into $s$ equivalent classes if I am not mistaken. Do not think this affects any proof but just wanted to confirm a related issue. Thanks!